# ¿Como consigo un atributo de un DetailPage desde un MasterPage?

Tags: c#, xamarin, map, position, xamarinforms

os comento.
Tengo una app creada en Xamarin forms en la que muestro un mapa con varios puntos señalados en el mismo.
Lo que intento hacer es, desde mi Master Page, hacer uso de la posición actual del usuario para guardarla como un nuevo punto en el mapa. Os paso las capturas que considero más importantes y si necesitáis cualquier otro dato os lo doy sin problema.

Esta es la clase MasterPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Sexcondites2._0
```

{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
{
public MasterPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
Init();
}

```
    private void Init()
    {
        List<Index> buttonIndex = new List<Index>
        {
            new Index{IndexTitle = "Nuevo Sexcondite",IndexDetail="Pulsa para guardar un nuevo sexcondite", IndexImage = "new_64px.png"}
        };
        ButtonsListView.ItemsSource = buttonIndex;
        ButtonsListView.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 0, 0);

        List<Index> pointsIndex = new List<Index>
        {
            new Index{IndexTitle = "Privacidad",IndexDetail="Puntos de privacidad del lugar", IndexImage = "heart_64px.png"},
            new Index{IndexTitle = "Paisaje",IndexDetail="Puntos del paisaje del lugar", IndexImage = "sun_64px.png"},
            new Index{IndexTitle = "Coche",IndexDetail="Necesitas un vehículo?", IndexImage = "car_64px.png"},
        };
        PointsListView.ItemsSource = pointsIndex;
        PointsListView.Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 0, 0);

        List<Index> markersIndex = new List<Index>
        {
            new Index{IndexTitle = "Fondo blanco",IndexDetail="Puedes ir sin tener un vehículo", IndexImage = "marker_blanco_verde.png"},
            new Index{IndexTitle = "Fondo de color",IndexDetail="Necesitas un vehículo", IndexImage = "marker_verde.png"},

            new Index{IndexTitle = "Color rosa",IndexDetail="Menos de 2 puntos de privacidad", IndexImage = "marker_rosa.png"},
            new Index{IndexTitle = "Color azul",IndexDetail="Entre 2 y 3 puntos de privacidad", IndexImage = "marker_azul.png"},
            new Index{IndexTitle = "Color verde",IndexDetail="Más de 3 puntos de privacidad", IndexImage = "marker_verde.png"}
        };
        MarkersListView.ItemsSource = markersIndex;
        MarkersListView.Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 0, 0);

        Detail = new NavigationPageHeader(new MainPage())
        {
            LeftColor = Color.FromHex(Application.Current.Resources["primaryColorDark"].ToString()),
            RightColor = Color.FromHex(Application.Current.Resources["primaryColorLight"].ToString())
        };
    }

    private void ButtonsListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as Index;
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.IndexTitle.Equals("Nuevo Sexcondite"))
            {
                //Aquí necesito que llegue la posición del usuario
                //Detail = new PinFormView(position);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Index
{
    public string IndexTitle { get; set; }
    public string IndexDetail { get; set; }
    public string IndexImage { get; set; }
}
```

}

Y esta es la MainPage de la que quiero sacar la posición actual del usuario, ya lo hago en el evento OnMapClicked y funciona perfectamente

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetCustomMap();
    }

    public void SetCustomMap()
    {
        CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap
        {
            MapType = MapType.Street,
            IsShowingUser = true
        };
        customMap.MapClicked += OnMapClicked;
        Content = customMap;

        //Genero los marcadores iniciales
        DatabasePin pin1 = new DatabasePin
        {
            name = "Puente Romana",
            privacyPoints = 1,
            viewPoints = 4,
            needCar = false,
            latitude = 42.115654,
            longitude = -8.812588,
            description = "Es un puente"
        };
        DatabasePin pin2 = new DatabasePin
        {
            name = "Parking de Playa América",
            privacyPoints = 3,
            viewPoints = 3,
            needCar = true,
            latitude = 42.128781,
            longitude = -8.819042,
            description = "El párking"
        };

        //Añado los markers a la base de datos            
        DatabaseController.Insert(new List<DatabasePin> { pin1, pin2 });

        //Añado los marcadores al mapa
        customMap.AddPins(DatabaseController.Read());

        //Me sitúo en la ubicación del usuario
        GetLocation(customMap);
    }

    private void OnMapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new ConfirmPopupView(new Position(e.Position.Latitude, e.Position.Longitude)));
    }

    public async void GetLocation(CustomMap customMap)
    {
        Location location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
        if (location == null)
        {
            location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest
            {
                DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
            }); ;
        }
        customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius((new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude)),
            Distance.FromKilometers(1)));
    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano y como os dije, si necesitaseis cualquier infomación adicional no dudeis en consultarme.